# FB messenger bot api, Is it can send attach file other than images, audio, VDO to user?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, messenger, facebook-messenger

Hi i want to send daily summary report to users via messenger bot.

but the message is long. I want to attach file .TXT send to users.

what API request JS obj i can use.

I see the document support only imges, audio, vdo.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/send-api-reference

Comment: It appears that Facebook does not want you to do this. Perhaps you could post your TXT file on a website and have your message send a link to it.

Comment: The desktop browser seems to accomplish sending a TXT file by first doing a post to upload.php, then one to send_messages.php ... the platform API does not get involved.

Comment: @RossPresser The first option is most suitable for me. I will upload to S3 then send link to view TXT file.